# send a mail with mutilple files in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

three or four files ( *_error.txt ) there in path. I want to send a mail with those attachments. No of attachment is not stable. it's vary.

```
echo "Agents are started" | mailx -s "test" -a "ud-agt-dev1-05_error.txt" -a "*error.txt" kalselva@mail.com -r agent@mail.com
```

But its not working.

Else please suggest me any other better one with example

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You are getting an error? You are not getting errors, but the email does not get sent? The email gets sent, but does not contain what you expect?

Comment: There are many versions and variants of `mailx` so if you need help with its behavior, it would be useful to include its version number and information about your OS and version.

Comment: The usual workaround is to use `mutt` because it is reasonably standard, both in terms of stability and in terms of installed base.

Answer (score 1):

The -a argument of `mailx` obviously has to be a single file, i.e. no wildcards allowed. When I run an equivalent of your `mailx`-call I get the error

> cannot open *error.txt

You can simply add as many `-a filename`s as you need, i.e. like this:

```
echo "Agents are started" | mailx -s "test" -a "ud-agt-dev1-05_error.txt"  $(ls *error.txt |xargs -i echo -a {}) kalselva@mail.com -r agent@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use another tools to send email.
One example is mutt.

This is an interactive, text-oriented e-mail client. Not very useful for usage in a script, one might think. But on closer view the program turns out to provide an easy way to send e-mails with file attachments.

```
mutt -s "Subject line" -a file.jpg hey@sweden.org < main_body.txt
```

how to specify four important parts of an e-mail:

- The recipient ("hey@sweden.org")
- The main body of the e-mail (read from standard input, here redirected from the file "main_body.txt)
- An attachment (with option -a)
- A subject line (option -s)

We could have added more attachments by using multiple -a options.
You can check more info about mutt on the web.

Hope it helps.
Bye